# JSON serialize nullpointer not handled with single line if

Tags: java, json

I can't understand what's going on here.. I have a class:

```
public abstract class ReservationDTO {

    private String currency;
    private Double price;


    public abstract ReservationType getType();

    public String getCurrency() {
        return this.currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {

        // if (this.price != null) {
        // return Math.ceil(this.price);
        // }
        // return null;

        return (this.price != null ? Math.ceil(this.price) : this.price);

        // return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

And one child class:

```
public class CarReservationDTO
    extends ReservationDTO {

    private String carModel;

    public String getCarModel() {
        return this.carModel;
    }

    public void setCarModel(String carModel) {
        this.carModel = carModel;
    }

    @Override
    public ReservationType getType() {
        return ReservationType.CAR;
    }

}
```

Some of the objects have the price set and some others don't. That's why I made some change in the getPrice() method.

First I had:

```
public Double getPrice() {
    if (this.price != null) {
        return Math.ceil(this.price);
    }
    return this.price;
}
```

And that worked just fine, if the price was there then it parsed in the json without decimals (because of the Math.ceil).
And if it was null, then it returned null.

But then I wanted to use single line if:

```
public Double getPrice() {
    return (this.price != null ? Math.ceil(this.price) : this.price);
}
```

And that trowed:

`Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.milware.dto.CollectionContainer["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.milware.dto.CarReservationDTO["price"]); nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: com.milware.dto.CollectionContainer["items"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.milware.dto.CarReservationDTO["price"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:194)`

If I change that line to:

```
    return (this.price != null ? Math.ceil(this.price) : null);
```

it works, but I don't like the last "null"..

I can't understand why would it throw that exception in the first place..

Comment: Can you add the whole exception that gets thrown?  (through reference chain..

Comment: @Marc I added the entire message now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about type.  The type of the ternary expression

```
(this.price != null ? Math.ceil(this.price) : this.price)
```

is determined statically, at compile time, based on the types of its second and third operands.  In this case, those operand types are `double` and `java.lang.Double`.  Either one can be converted to the other, courtesy of auto[un]boxing, and the compiler chooses `double`.  When `this.price` turns out to contain `null`, however, the resulting autounboxing fails with a `NullPointerException`.

You should be able to do it in one line with this expression:

```
(this.price != null ? Double.valueOf(Math.ceil(this.price)) : this.price)
```

That alleviates the type uncertainty, preventing Java from trying to unbox `this.price` when it is `null` (or at all).

For what it's worth, I personally prefer the form with the explicit `null`.  I find it much clearer.

Comment: Can't believe it was that ! I didn't know that the compiler did things like that, that's amazing to know. Thanks !!